# How to implement project versioning in my app

Tags: mongodb, express, nuxt.js, editorjs

Hi i use a NuxtJS/express/MongoDb app, in the app i have a notion-like text editor called editorJS.

I would like to have a history trace of the changes in this editor, just like notion.so does.

In this editor I can have: text, lists, images, files, datatables

Does anyone know how i could do this ?

This is what i would like to have
[image]

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: I am thinking of using some king of git maybe, and add a commit for each update, but is there a better solution ?